# Regarding iOS CLLocation API CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid, how does OS treat GPS valid or not?

Tags: ios, gps

Regarding iOS CLLocation API CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid, how does OS treat CLLocationCoordinate2D (lat and lon) valid or not?  As you know lat and lon in CLLocationCoordinate2D are all double data type, double means more precious, such as 3.24579999999, it will always be treated as invalid by CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid. This kind of problem will always occur in server protocol definition, which needs to change from NSString to double value。Anyone who experienced the same issue please discuss together and thanks in advance.

```
BOOL CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(CLLocationCoordinate2D coord)
```

Comment: The [documentation for CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationFunctions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009576-CH2-SW3) is clear on what "valid" means.  Why would `3.24579999999` be "invalid"?  What you are talking about is _precision_.  That is something completely different from what this function does which is check whether the degrees are in a valid range.  What is the real problem you are having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are intermixing 2 things:

1. `CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid` describes whether the values (lat/lon) are in valid range.
2. The LocationManager will mark an invalid location in the field `horizontalAccuracy`of `CLLLocation`, by a negative value. This CLLocation is delivered e.g in `locationManager:didUpdateLocations`. Such an invalid  marked coordinate means there was not a sufficient (GPS) position (navigation solution). Although the lat/lon values of that  invalid CLLocation could still could be in valid range (see CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid)

Further to topic 2, iOS does not state when it marks a location as invalid, but most probably it will directly use the fix-valid flag of the GPS Protocoll. (chip to iOS intern)

Comment: Ask this question dues to the source of GPS value in my projects comes from 3rd party, on my side we use CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid method to check whether it is valid or not. For some cases it reports invalid but we don't find any exception in GPS (lat, lon) value. I wonder how does Apple implement  this logic?  Thanks very much.

Comment: There must be a bug on your side. The lat/lon coordinates delivered in CLLocatoin should always be in valid range, just give an example which lat/lon  pair was delivered and is invalid. However you cannot check the location valid/invalid (GPS) position by using CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid, except when yoz  activley replace the lat/lon valu by a special invalid valid (e.g -888888) in case the horicontalAccuracy is negative.

Comment: Alex, thanks for your reply. check GPS validation dues to found crash on MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coord2d, 10000, 10000);    [_mapView setRegion:region]; if GPS coord2d is invalid. It can be treated as a protected solution.

Comment: 3rd party server only provides lat and lon for shop location, no horicontalAccuracy available, which is a big headache us to test whether valid or not.

Comment: if 3rd party: then if cord = (0,0) then invalid, if CLLocationcoordinate2DIsValid == false then invalid. Further you may want to avoid polar regions: if lat >80 or lat < -80 then invalid. More you cannot do.